# SmoothDensityHistogram's "Intensity" dfun

Tags: plotting

I'm having a strange issue with SmoothDensityHistogram in 11.3.0.  I can easily represent my data with the "PDF" dfun:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 0.04, "PDF"]
```

[image]

But when i try "Intensity"...

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 0.04, "Intensity"]
```

[image]

I've tried changing the value of 0.04, making it Automatic, or removing it entirely.  I don't understand why the intensity count won't display.  Though the plot may look the same (if it worked) in either case, I want my plot legend to be intensity counts instead of a probability.

EDIT::

My particular data doesn't matter.  Try with any random data set and the behavior will be the same.  For instance...

```
data = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];
```

---

It sounds like this is a new issue in 11.3.  I'll report it as a bug.

Comment: Please, post your `data`to get help from anyone here...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas See the edit.  The actual data set doesn't matter.  I reproduced the behavior with a random distribution of points.

Comment: Strange. The problem does not seem to occur in **11.1** - `SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 0.04, "Intensity"]` works for me.

Comment: This seems to be very much a regression from v11.2. The following works on it, but not at all on 11.3: `SmoothDensityHistogram[RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[2]], 1000], Automatic, "Intensity"]`

Comment: Does anyone know what the difference between `"Intensity"` and `"PDF"` options are supposed to be? It seems like the plots should be identical...

Comment: @ulvi the plots should look the same, but the meaning of the bins will be different when a legend is involved.  PDF gives the probability distribution between the bins, and Intensity gives the number of elements counted in each bin.